# What is faster: sorted collection or list and linq queries on it (with intensive insertion/deletion)?

Tags: c#, performance

I have a dilemma. I have to implement prioritized queue (custom sort order). I need to insert/process/delete a lot of messages per second by using it (~100-1000).

Which design is faster at run-time?

1) custom sorted by priority collection (list)

2) list(non-sorted collection) + linq query all time when I need to process (dequeue) message

3) something else

**ADDED:**

**SOLUTION:**

List (Dictionary) of queues by priority: `SortedList<int, VPair<bool, Queue<MyMessage>>>`
where int - priority, bool - true if it is not empty queue

Comment: RTFM (aka MSDN). They list all the complexity of list operations. Failing that, just consult a book on algorithms and data structures.

Comment: You need to more reads than writes?

Comment: Or, failing that - do your own benchmarks. =)

Comment: @Magnus it's a queue. one enqueue and dequeue (by priority).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats your read/write ratio? Are multiple threads involved, if so, how?

As always when asking about performance, benchmark both code-paths and see for yourself (this is especially true the more specific your problem domain is).

Comment: it's a queue. one enqueue and one dequeue (by priority). No locks (locking is implemented on high level, please skip lock restrictions, no locks).

Comment: And what is Priority (type?) I would consider seperating them to different Lists on enqueue, so Something like an Array of Qeueus where the index is your priority, then you can just dequeue. Alternatively,  Dictionary<Priority, Queue<YourType>>>. On dequeue check in highest Priority order which are empty. You could also remember highst-non-empty stack on enqueue, but thats micro-optimiztion (edited to change Stack to Queue)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to know for sure is to measure the performance for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, finding an element in an unsorted data structure takes O(n) on average (one pass over the data structure). Binary Search trees have an average insertion complexity on O(log n) and also an average lookup complexity of O(log n). So in theory using something like that would be faster. In reality the overhead or the shape of the data might kill the theoretical advantage.

Also if your custom sort order can change at runtime you might have to rebuild the sorted data structure which is an additional performance hit.

In the end: If it is important for your application then try the different approaches and benchmark it yourself - it's the only way to be certain that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing sorting will always incur an insertion performance overhead as far as I'm aware. If there's no need for the sorting then use a nice generic Dictionary which will provide a quick lookup based on your unique key.